# Missing SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 enum value during XML serialization

Tags: c#, .net, enums, xml-serialization, sgen

I have the following simple XML serializable type:

```cs
[XmlType]
public class TestType
{
    public System.Net.SecurityProtocolType ProtocolType { get; set; }
}

var instanceToSerialize = new TestType { ProtocolType = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 };
```

I can serialize an instance of this object just fine on my computer and several computers. But on one of the computers I have tested, I am getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: '4080' is not a valid value for System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter.FromEnum(Int64 val, String[] vals, Int64[] ids, String typeName)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterTestType.Write1_SecurityProtocolType(SecurityProtocolType v)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterTestType.Write3_TestType(String n, String ns, TestType o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterTestType.Write4_TestType(Object o)
```

I have compared the `sgen.exe` generated code for working and failing cases. On the working case I have this code generated:

```cs
string Write1_SecurityProtocolType(global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType v) {
    string s = null;
    switch (v) {
        case global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Ssl3: s = @"Ssl3"; break;
        case global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls: s = @"Tls"; break;
        case global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls11: s = @"Tls11"; break;
        case global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls12: s = @"Tls12"; break;
        default: s = FromEnum(((System.Int64)v), new string[] {@"Ssl3", 
            @"Tls", 
            @"Tls11", 
            @"Tls12"}, new System.Int64[] {(long)global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Ssl3, 
            (long)global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls, 
            (long)global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls11, 
            (long)global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls12}, @"System.Net.SecurityProtocolType"); break;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Whereas on the failing code, this is the generated code:

```cs
string Write1_SecurityProtocolType(global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType v) {
    string s = null;
    switch (v) {
        case global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls: s = @"Tls"; break;
        case global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls11: s = @"Tls11"; break;
        case global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls12: s = @"Tls12"; break;
        default: s = FromEnum(((System.Int64)v), new string[] {@"Tls", 
            @"Tls11", 
            @"Tls12"}, new System.Int64[] {(long)global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls, 
            (long)global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls11, 
            (long)global::System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.@Tls12}, @"System.Net.SecurityProtocolType"); break;
    }
    return s;
}
```

You can notice that the code for `Ssl3` enum member is not generated on the failing case. Do you have any idea why that code is missing?

Comment: Check the versions of .NET installed on the PCs.  I believe the newest version 4.6 may have removed that option.

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm nope, I have 4.6.1 and 4.6.2 installed and 4.6.x still has Ssl3 enum member.

Answer (score 2):

The plain diagnostic is that SGen.exe was run with the wrong reference assemblies.  The `/reference` command line options matter, if it isn't used then it falls back to the ones in c:\windows\microsoft.net

The shoe fits, the SecurityProtocolType enum has been quite fickle.  It was changed from .NET 4.0 to 4.5, adding the Tls11 and Tls12 enum members.  Lots of Q+A here about it to get them enabled even on a project that targets 4.0.  And there is a pretty big problem with SSLv3, it has been compromised [beyond repair](http://disablessl3.com/#why).  Accordingly Microsoft is trying to stop programmers from using it, something you can see back in [the .NETCore declaration](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/ae3dfc48662d72adec7bbd3f4700bf55e113a00f/src/System.Net.Primitives/ref/System.Net.Primitives.cs#L440).  The [Obsolete] attribute is one that SGen.exe pays attention to.

It isn't otherwise obvious to me what flavor of reference assembly could have been used.  While SslProtocols.Ssl3 has the [Obsolete] attribute in .NETCore, the SecurityProtocolType enum member [does not](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.ServicePoint/ref/System.Net.ServicePoint.cs#L55).  So SGen.exe accidentally using a .NETCore reference assembly doesn't explain it.  Something like Mono or Xamarin doesn't easily explain it.  Silverlight or a PCL reference assembly doesn't explain it, at least not on my machine.  A wonky beta version is always a possibility.

Unless you have a known reason to use an unusual `/reference` argument for SGen.exe, the best recommendation is to reinstall the .NET Framework on that machine.  And stop using Ssl3, it is truly obsolete.